# Pipe ordering matters? Piping stdin into an http request and piping the result to stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, stream

I am looking at the problem 'http client'

I made the following solution which passes 2/3 tests:

```
request = require 'request'

#Generate a read/writable stream piping into the outbuff
myRequest = request.post("http://localhost:8099").pipe(process.stdout)

process.stdin.pipe(myRequest)
```

...with the following error:

```
operator: equal
expected:
  'azzwcc\njup\nvccvwcddun\nmukp\nikeos.\nPaps\'w\nheghuuyuuv\nwu\nbzcawcsenvzm\nouggkneoasc\n'
actual:
  'allsee\nfor\ndeedsetton\nyour\nquick.\nTark\'s\nbimboowood\nso\npleasekindly\ncommunicake\n'
```

However, when I pipe the output in this order, it works fine.

```
request = require 'request'

#Generate a read/writable stream piping into the outbuff
myRequest = request.post("http://localhost:8099")

process.stdin.pipe(myRequest).pipe(process.stdout)
```

Shouldn't these two solutions be the same? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you're passing the http response to stdout (but never writing to the request stream). Then you're passing input from stdin directly to stdout. So you have two streams writing to stdout. The resulting situation looks something like:

```
HTTP RESPONSE -----
                  |
                  v
STDIN -------> STDOUT
```

In the second example, you have input from stdin passed to the request stream and the response from that request passed to stdout. The resulting situation looks something like:

```
STDIN ----> HTTP REQUEST/RESPONSE ----> STDOUT
```

Comment: OK, I think this is where the fundamental misunderstanding lies. I really need to understand the anatomy of a pipe call.

When I have `A.pipe(B).pipe(C)` What is returned and what is the role of A, B and C?

Comment: As [the documentation for `.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) mentions, the destination stream is returned. This is what allows easy chaining of streams. In your A-B-C example, A is at least a Readable stream, B is some sort of Duplex stream, and C is at least a Writable stream. `A.pipe(B)` returns `B` and `A.pipe(B).pipe(C)` returns `C`. This is equivalent to `A.pipe(B); B.pipe(C);`.

Comment: I see, so the issue is that .pipe() hasn't returned an object which encompasses the entire stream, so it doesn't make sense to pipe something into it and expect it to squirt through A. Is that it? So it's one way usage, and I should only use the result for its output.

Comment: Aaaaand your edit just resolved my confusion hahah. Thank you so much for taking the time and explaining it to me. So if I wanted to put something into the beginning, I would just have to do `Something.pipe(A)` and it would go through the whole chain?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, provided that `A` is a duplex stream (if you have another `.pipe()` after that).